# How to provide named function to map without lambdas

Tags: scala, lambda, anonymous-function, future

I want to make my `Future`s usage more constructive by using less lambdas. At the moment I'm using map and lambdas to access futures' results. For e.g.:

```
val rateQuote = future {
  connection.getCurrentValue(USD)
}
val purchase = rateQuote map { quote =>  
  if (isProfitable(quote)) connection.buy(amount, quote)
  else throw new Exception("not profitable")
}
purchase onSuccess {
  case _ => println("Purchased " + amount + " USD")
}
```

Instead of providing a lambda (anonymous function) for each `map`, I would like to provide a named function/method instead. How would I do that? E.g.:

```
val rateQuote = future {
  connection.getCurrentValue(USD)
}
def namedFunction(arg: Arg) = 
  if (isProfitable(quote)) connection.buy(amount, quote)
  else throw new Exception("not profitable")

val purchase = rateQuote map { quote => namedFunction }
```

or even better

```
val purchase = rateQuote map namedFunction
```

My main concern is that I find myself moving too much logic into lambdas and debugging is harder than with named functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I got you right it shouldn't be much harder:

```
def buyIfProfitable(quote: Quote) = 
  if (isProfitable(quote)) connection.buy(amount, quote)
  else throw new Exception("not profitable")

val purchase = rateQuote.map(q => buyIfProfitable(q))
```

or simply

```
val purchase = rateQuote.map(buyIfProfitable)
```

Answer (score 1):

To augment om-nom-nom's answer - at worst use a partially applied function:

> val purchase = rateQuote.map( buyIfProfitable _ )